# Change colors of TextFormField using ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

I would like to change the color of the `PrefixIcon` and `suffixIcon` as well as the color of the cursor using `ThemeData` when the `TextFormField` gets the focus to match with the color of the `TextFormField`'s border color.

[image]

Also I would like to understand the difference between `border`, `enabledBorder` and `focusBorder`. I went through the documentation but couldn't understand.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

define a variable of color type and initialized it with a default and change its value within 'onTap' handler of TextFormField. and use setState also